# Where is the line for yes/no questions?

Tags: discussion, questions

As a daily visitor I should first report that the quality of questions for the tags I monitor is on a clear up-tick.  So whatever's being done in the background is having a favourable result.

Having said that, I wanted to check on the question type that has been been appearing more frequently.  It goes along the lines of...

> I have some doodlies that need to be co-mingled with some squats.
>   (...blah blah blah...)  I would like to use humpers on the carumpers
>   to accomplish that.  I searched and could not find a definitive
>   answer.  Is it OK?

Technically, the correct answer consists of a single word:

> Yes.

A more cynical response would be:

> Do tell us how you got on finding out about this.

And the SO "party line" is to close vote on the grounds of 'cannot be reproduced' or 'too broad' etc.  There are no specific grounds to close on '**a yes/no question is not suitable**', and indeed some of them are interesting.   And against that backdrop I see both higher ups (as vaunted role models) and noobs (looking for low hanging fruit) taking a shot at an answer...

Where is the line drawn on yes/no questions?

Comment: I guess that Yes/No questions (or more like polls) could be useful in some situations, giving the community the ability to quickly send the OP in a suitable direction based on the "common/best practice" decided by the vote, with the ability to also detail (if you want) your choice in a comment or answer

Comment: A problem with those kinds of question is often also that they are worded not like "can I do X?" answer "no" but worded as "tell be how to do x". and then there is no real way to answer them, as answering "no you can not do it" will get your answer deleted, but there is no way to answer it other than with "no".

Comment: IMO, the problem isn't about the binary question, but about the binary answer. There are _very_ few situations where answers cannot be expanded on from a yes/no.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that I've not noticed any improvement in [tag:c++], [tag:php], [tag:javascript] or [tag:mysql].

Comment: [Should yes or no questions be put on hold?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258270) - I find it ridiculous how different essentially the same question gets treated sometimes (the first isn't phrased as well, but I mean - `-11` and closed vs `+10`).

Comment: I find these questions are almost always a guise for debugging help. At least in the Java space these questions are almost always accompanied by code with obvious errors. That is why they are closed, usually as "unclear what you're asking" or "lacks minimal information" because what the OP needs to do is tell us what the problem is, in other words, these questions are often actually a code dump.

Comment: So you are talking just yes/no questions and not say should I eat vanilla ice cream or chocolate ice cream tonight?  Yes/no could either be factual or opinion (close those) while the other binary question that I model is more opinion (close those).  Either way, opinion creeping into these questions is the big problem.

Comment: Many of these questions come in the form "Is this OK?" to which you sometimes just say: "Yes, in all regards.". The last part to get over the character requirements.

Comment: Answer: between the yes and the no. That line is actually called a slash, [virgule](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/virgule), or solidus

Comment: @dbliss, it's kind of you to ask. And yes, British is one of my three  nationalities, arguably my favourite. Thanks again for your enquiry and do keep a stiff pecker; there's a bit of foul weather to beware of.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

I would say that if a question can ONLY be answered meaningfully with 'Yes/No', then it should be closed.

However, that's not why most of these are closed.  Most of these are either asking questions like "Is my program good?" or "Did I do this [complicated thing] right?" - and often that's not a good question, anyway, binary or not.  The former is basically an opinion, while the latter is either an opinion or often too long to be answerable here.

The right way to deal with otherwise-acceptable questions, ie, a question that would be good if it were *not* a yes/no question, is to edit it to be that otherwise-acceptable question.  "Can I write a bogum by escarpating a humphus?" might be a binary question, but if "How do you write a bogum?" is a good question, and a good answer might (or might not) be "Escarpate a humphus", then edit the question to be that, and include the "escarpating a humphus" as "I tried...", which we always like to see.

These are often a subset of [XY problem questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), which means they have a problem, but they don't ask how to solve the problem; they instead ask about the answer they picked.  Sometimes that's okay, but often a better question is the original problem.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773

Comment: @gnat Nice find, that's a much better explanation of the same answer.

Comment: @Joe, thanks.  I have been interpreting some as "I am having an argument with my boss/colleague who says I am doing it wrong.  Please support my point of view so I can show it to him/her and thereby win the argument."  But's that is an INFERRED message.  For all I know, it could be professional curiosity.

Comment: In cases where I can infer what the OP is actually seeking, I sometimes explicitly state what I think they're asking, and answer that.  I'm loath to edit other people's questions to say what I think they wanted to know, because my inferences aren't always correct.  Further, while I appreciate some edits to my answers that fix genuine mistakes, there are other times I've happened upon answers of mine which were edited to change something which was correct but counterintuitive to something which was intuitive but wrong.  In some cases, that's been an impetus to my improving the answer...

Comment: ...so as to make clear why my answer, though counterintuitive, is in fact correct, but perhaps what's needed is a form of edit which would request moderation by the original poster who could then accept the edit, reject, or use it as a basis for further editing.  BTW, if I see that an edit has been proposed for a post of mine, and has been rejected, is there any way as the author of the post I can counteract that rejection and give the editor credit for the revision?

Answer (score 2):

If a question provides some code and asks a yes/no question about it, the question is likely to be worthless to anyone except the OP, and similar questions could be repeated infinitely. They seem the antithesis of questions useful for building a repository of useful questions and answers. My instinct is that therefore such questions should be off topic.

The question has a yes/no answer, so clearly not *too broad*. In most cases I've seen, the question ask a about something that has a generally accepted precise definition, so not *primarily opinion based*.

Once there was a *too localized* close reason, which would be applicable. But that [was removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/184154/closing-changes-on-hold-unclear-too-broad-opinion-based-off-topic-reasons).

It can be useful to consider *why the OP can not answer the question themselves*. If the question is ["is this code an example of *X*"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/317526/is-is-this-an-example-of-an-example-of-a-bad-question?lq=1), the reason is because the OP does not have a good understanding of *X*. So the question is either *unclear what you are asking* (what *precisely* about *X* do you not understand), or a *duplicate* of a canonical question asking "What is _X".

Answer (score 2):

From the [Don't Ask page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), constructive subjective questions...

> - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
> - tend to have long, not short, answers
>   ...
> - insist that opinion be backed up with facts and references

Really, that's true of *all* answers. A good question should invite some explanation and justification. Just answering "yes" or "no" with no further explanation or justification is not a good answer, and questions that are asking for bad answers shouldn't be asked here.

Think about it this way: suppose that I ask "is *x* possible?" and someone simply says "no." All I know at this point is that some stranger on the Internet claims that what I'm trying to achieve is impossible. I have no idea *why* it's not possible, and the fact that I have no proof or explanation for the answer means that I haven't actually learned anything and I don't even have a way of verifying whether the answer is correct or not. I suppose that I could look at the voting, but if I do that the question has effectively descended into an opinion poll ("75% of those surveyed believe that *x* is impossible!").

So really, the line is whether the question invites explanation and justification or just a quick "yes or no?" answer.

Answer (score 1):

> I have some doodlies that need to be co-mingled with some squats. (...blah blah blah...) I would like to use humpers on the carumpers to accomplish that. I searched and could not find a definitive answer. Is it OK?

To me this question would be borderline unclear. What is meant by "Is it OK"? That may mean something like "Will it work?" or "Is it considered good practice?" or something completely different. The asker should specify what he actually wants to know.

I imagined more questions of type

> I have problem X and would like to do Y to solve X. Will Y work?

which would be a clear Yes/No question (and an XY question).

For these type of question I always imagined an implicit addition:

> I have problem X and would like to do Y to solve X. Will Y work? If not how could I solve X?

Which makes it more than a simple Yes/No question.

It still suffers from the fact that the asker could have easily verified himself/herself if Y works. The asker should explain why checking if Y works was not feasible. That finally gives a form of questions (neither XY nor Yes/No) that I would like to see here.

> I have problem X. I thought about doing Y to solve it. I could not do Y because of ... or I tried Y did it not work. How do I solve X?

In case of a Yes/No question I propose to first ask the question creator if he himself already tried it and what the outcomes were and in case the outcome was negative or the trial could not be performed, I would answer it as if it were of the form given in the last paragraph (maybe also editing the question accordingly afterwards).