# What to do with this specific yes/no question about red/black trees?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, specific-question

Someone just posted this question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/25120574/1313143

**Edit - question was removed.** Original content follows:

> ### Red black tree property check
>
> A height-balanced BST is a binary search tree in which the height of
>   any two siblings differ by at most 1. In a height-balanced BST on N nodes, the height is
>   logarithmic in N.
>
> Is the above statement true?

**The user just posted a very similar question:** https://stackoverflow.com/q/25123205/1313143

This seems yanked straight from some kind of test. I'm inclined to close for being too broad. Obviously yes/no can be sufficient here, but expanding on it would probably require somewhere between 3 paragraphs and a whole textbook (note: that's a guesstimate, I don't know anything about the technical topic at hand to be honest).

I've read [Where is the line for yes/no questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/258630/1313143) here on meta, but I'm having trouble to apply the answer in this case.

What also stings me with this one is that the user shows no research effort at all, but there isn't a clearly defined closing reason for that either.

Comment: OP deleted his question before I was able to CV it, but [here's a dupe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14539141/why-is-the-height-of-a-balanced-binary-tree-logn-proof).

Comment: I haven't seen the first question, but the question you linked to is most certainly not a yes/no question. It asks to prove something. @Stijn

Comment: @Stijn as 11684 points out, that was not a duplicate at all. It is not a simple yes/no to begin with but it also had an entirely different formulation.

Comment: Algorithms aren't really my thing, and the one I linked to is formulated differently, but I still think it's a dupe. A good answer on the now deleted question would be "yes, here's why", not a simple "yes" or "no".

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester You can infer the answer to the now deleted question from that one. If you can *prove* that the height is log(n) then the statement that the height is log(n) is true.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist yes, that is true.

Comment: Deleted 10 minutes after it was asked.  I guess we weren't fast enough to help him with his exam.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Sadly, that is probably exactly what happened.

Comment: It was reposted: [Red black tree property check](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25123205). I've voted to close it as a dupe (thanks @Stijn).

Comment: @MartijnPieters you were a little bit too hasty I'm afraid (so was I at first). It is now a different question technical-wise, but of the exact same nature as the one he posted earlier.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester: Yeah, you are right. Not a great question, but I'll retract the dupe vote.

Comment: @MartijnPieters too bad it's not possible to change the close vote afterwards...

Comment: @MartijnPieters: That one's gone too, now.

Comment: In this case, the answer is **yes** and the question should be voted to close. There was a previous option to close as *too localized* which sadly isn't anymore. And the way this question is posted, it is too localized and it is obviously homework for a lazy guy/girl with lot of spare time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters that's not a repost, is a complete different question that falls in a "yes/no" category, and the answer for that is **no**. And the possible duplicate is not the right duplicate.

Comment: `"I don't know anything about the technical topic at hand to be honest."` So typical of mods across this platform ...

Comment: @m_vdbeek I'm not a mod. Also, it doesn't always require technical knowledge to judge the quality of a question, most factors are not related to the technical level of it. I'm pretty confident that mods do not tackle a question or answer if they are unsure because they don't understand the contents. Neither do I.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Closing a topic is moderation though. Anyways moding here is basically people farming points by running an autocorrect on questions.

Comment: @m_vdbeek If you really think so, post your problem on [Meta.SE] and see how much downvotes (disagreement) you get. I'm sorry that you see it that way. It can't even be true because there are no points to be gained by correcting questions. If you didn't know yet, there is a difference between the community employing their earned moderating priveleges and community _elected_ moderators. The first category is what keeps SE sites clean and I assure you it has nothing to do with "farming points", as you don't get points for doing that. Neither do elected mods, for the record.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester I'm not the only one feeling like this. Post this same question on HackerNews or Reddit and you'll see what I mean. And you DO get badges for the number of edits you do so there's still an advantage in farming autocorrect edits. e.g: https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4131462

Comment: @m_vdbeek this isn't HackerNews on Reddit. SE has its own rules and you can leave it or take it basically. If you don't agree with how the site works, you can either find other communities to get your questions answered, or you can discuss the platform and suggest improvements on [meta.SE]. If you think mods or people who make moderating decisions aren't doing a good job, feel free to post on the meta of the site in question. As for your remark on "autocorrect edits", they still need to get approved by the community. But in the end, what does it matter to you that people get virtual badges...?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester You asked me to create a question on Meta which isn't really neutral ground. We're not on Reddit or HackerNews but you can read the feedback and take it into account nevertheless. And yes I do have a problem with badges not because they are worth anything but because they are used as some kind of legitimacy and authority.

Comment: @m_vdbeek Meta **is** neutral ground, why do you think it isn't? Everyone gets equal chance. And if you think it isn't neutral because you get a lot of downvotes, that's just because your opinion happens to be different from the majority. There's nothing wrong with that, but you must understand that the platform as a whole works like democracy: minorities can't win. And I've been there too but you need to give it a place and move on. After all this is just a small spot on the web and I think it's great that you even get the chance to bring things to the table. The community does have a say.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester How can you say that a subdomain of the same network is neutral ground ??? It's definitely not a democracy either, not by design but because only the "top" users actually participate. I never got downvoted for a question since I never posted a question here. It's not going to change anything for me so I don't care too much but it's just sad to see that no valid criticism from external sources is accepted. Try to ban edits with diffs smaller than 10 chars and remove badges for edits. You'll see all the pseudo-active-users coming from the wood-work.

Comment: @m_vdbeek There's already a limit for edits: If you're under 2k rep, you have to edit at least 6 characters, and then it gets reviewed and can be rejected. As for the "top users" participating, if you don't like that then get on here and participate. No one is stopping anyone from participating on Meta. If you want to give your opinion on a topic, then do it. I'm by no means a "top user", I've only earned 67 rep on this site. (I got an association bonus, that's why my rep is where it is) But I've been at least reading Meta, and participating. Don't blame others for your lack of motivation.

Comment: @Kendra You can blame / shame me all you want, in the end the quality of the community is going down and most people outside of the biased Meta community agrees. (c.f: my link to HN above.)

Answer (score -1):

EDIT: I'm leaving the answer for future reference, but I was wrong. Don't do this. (See comments.)

---

The original and pseudo-duplicate questions both seem like good candidates for migration to Computer Science SE. I'd flag for mod attention, and let it be dealt with according to that community's guidelines, which I know sounds like I'm saying "not our problem", but what I mean is "It's not our place to judge this question".

Comment: Sorry for the edits, I wanted to remove my upvote. Your answer isn't really an answer and moreover I don't fully agree with what you say. Low quality questions being migrated elsewhere aren't generally appreciated by the receiving SE site, even if it's more on-topic there than where it came from. The quality can be judged anywhere, the overhead of migration doesn't need to be added to that.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester It's my understanding that different SEs have different standards for what constitutes "low quality", but I'm definitely still a newcomer here. Edit and vote as you feel appropriate.

Comment: Moderators shouldn't be bothered with quite obviously bad questions, community can handle them appropriately.

Comment: The standards for quality are indeed _somewhat_ different on the individual SE sites, you are correct in that. But there is a lowest common denominator to question quality that applies network-wide. Even when visiting a completely new (to me) SE site I already have a certain idea which questions will be a good fit. The question I pointed to in my topic is obviously unfit for the entire network.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Noted. What about the user's revised version?

Comment: Is there a revised version? Where can I find it?

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester I mean the one linked in your question as "The user just posted a very similar question". That one seemed (before it was also deleted) somewhat higher quality to me than the original yes/no version, so I'm trying to calibrate my sense of where the "low quality" bar is.