# Moving discussion to chat fails with vague error message

Tags: bug, comments, chat

I was having a rather lengthy discussion with another user in the comments on [one of my questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267687/1313143), it was getting very off-topic and I was actually glad that the automatic link came up to invite the user to chat.

But it fails for unspecified reasons:

[image: Moving to chat fails - screenshot]
<sup>(the yellow stuff is mine)</sup>

I've refreshed and retried 3 times with the same results. What can be the cause? Is it because this happens on meta and meta does not have its own chat?

Comment: _Is it because this happens on meta and meta does not have its own chat?_ then we shouldn't have that option there. Good question.

Comment: Will people never learn to make useful error messages? :|

Comment: @BartoszKP `catch(Exception ex) { //this should never happen }` I believe it came from there somewhere.

Comment: Instinctively tried to close the error box...

Comment: @BenFortune I'm ashamed to admit I fell into the same trap on my own question. Damn those close buttons and their magnetic attractiveness!

Comment: The "Don't click" sign made me click it.

Comment: @Bolu would be nice if someone could confirm or refute that this is actually the cause. In case of the former, I would retag this as [meta-tag:bug].

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester, indeed. BTW I'm glad you didn't put a **X** on your alert...lol...

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester This happened to me today.

Comment: It's a bug. Just caught it in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39318370/google-sign-in-not-working-after-publishing-in-play-store?noredirect=1#comment65969310_39318370

Comment: its happening to me right now in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39471351/how-do-i-force-pouchdb-to-really-delete-records/39472702#

Comment: me also faced this.....

Comment: facing this with http://stackoverflow.com/a/40439358/2032943