# Moving the discussion to chat failed

Tags: support, comments, chat

On my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48480969/1595451) to [Google Apps Script to turn in, grade, and return a Google Classroom Assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48480059/1595451)

The link to move comments to a chat room fails.

> Please avoid extended discussions in comments. Would you like to automatically move this discussion to chat?

The error message is

> Moving the discussion to chat failed

There is an report about the same but it hasn't an answer

[Moving discussion to chat fails with vague error message](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267759/1595451)

Something else to do about this from my side?

---

Update

The problem hadn't occurred on another post where the other party has 20 rep -> [Run Google script on single sheet instead of entire spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48523280/1595451)

Comment: Maybe you get the error because the other party doesn't have chat privileges yet? If that is the reason the error message could be more clear, or even better: don't offer move to chat if you know it is going to fail

Comment: If my above comment is correct then we have a regression that used to work properly: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99047/is-21-not-enough-reputation-to-go-to-chat

Comment: @rene AFAIK, all other party will automatically get explicit write access when it's moved to the chat like [this example on Workplace.SE](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/72298/discussion-on-answer-by-the-snark-knight-it-seems-as-though-my-employer-wants-me?tab=access) (this is something that I have been wondering back then whether 1 rep user can chat or not).

Comment: @AndrewT. ok, I thought the 1 rep feature was only enabled during the mentoring experiment.

Comment: @AndrewT. It looks that the explicit it's not working on SO. Just a minute ago on a different thread where the other party has 27 rep the chat was created without any problems.