# C tag right-out hostile

Tags: discussion

I don't frequently post to the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag but when I do I'm trying to learn and I make sure that I don't open duplicates.

While I do get a lot of views (more than I'm used to in my usual tags at least) I also get down-votes without comments. I get voted-to-close with reason "too broad" on yes/no questions and so forth.

Example: [In what contexts are arrays not turned into pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26364288/in-what-contexts-are-arrays-not-turned-into-pointers)

An other example by another user: [C program with functionality as cp command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26363965/c-program-with-the-same-functionality-as-the-unix-cp-command)

Yes, he might have some bugs in his code but does that make his question -4 points worth of bad?

It's not hard to find similar questions which seem perfectly fine and have down-votes.

I think the guys over at [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) need a refresher on how/when to vote.

Comment: Re. "I get voted-to-close with reason "too broad" on yes/no questions" See [Where is the line for yes/no questions?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258630/where-is-the-line-for-yes-no-questions)

Comment: This is funny. Downvotes without comments. It's not only the C-tag, apparently.

Comment: [Voting is different on meta.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) Officially, votes on questions tagged [tag:feature-request] are used to signal agreement or disagreement. In practice, this often extends to non feature requests as well. Don't take it personally, it may just mean people don't see things the way you do. For example, they may think the examples you listed really *are* poor questions that deserved downvotes or close votes.

Comment: "This question does not show any research effort" clearly applies to that `cp` question. Simply reading the man pages for the relevant functions would show the mistake.

Comment: What's your question / concern here? I suspect you're getting downvoted because it just feels like you're venting, which - ok, if you need to vent fine but you gotta expect folks to be a bit annoyed. If you can suggest something constructive be done here, or turn this into more of a question ("Why was my [specific-question] downvoted / close-voted here?" or even "Why do I see so many downvotes in the C tag?") you'll probably get a better reception.

Comment: Easily found a duplicate for your first example.

Comment: Who *isn't* pissed off when having to use C?

Comment: first reasonable comment in this thread.

Comment: The C tag is riddled with inappropriate, ugly and downright insulting questions.  I didn't even bother to open the 'UNIX cp' question because I could smell the crap from outside. Typical example of why contribitors get pissed of with jerks:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26324713/improvement-of-code

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26366232/assignment-aand-precedence-of-operators-in-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26372902/convert-between-temperatures-in-c#comment41404959_26372902

Answer (score 7):

> I get voted-to-close with reason "too broad" on yes/no questions and so forth.

Yes/no questions are **by their very nature** likely to be too broad.

Example: "I'd like to flibble the foo. Is it possible?"

Is this person really expecting an answer that will simply be "yes" without an explanation how to do it? Or "no" without an explanation why it is not possible? Probably not, and as a matter of practice users of SO will interpret such question instead as "*How* can I flibble the foo? If I can't to this, then why not?" You won't find a rule that spells this out but this is the custom, because if we did not do this, then we'd have to add a close reason to flat out close "yes/no" questions.

If the answer is "no" then *perhaps* one can make the case that the answer is not too broad. There may be just one *salient* reason why it can't be done, and all answers would be merely restating the same reason in different words.

However, if the answer is "yes" then how should the answer be framed? If the OP cannot flibble the foo, is it because the OP has a problem with the language? Is it because the OP does not know how to flibble? Is it because the OP is approaching the foo incorrectly? Is it an issue with logic? I've seen such questions get a bunch of answers, only for the OP to comment on all answers that they are not actually answering the *actual* problem the OP was having. This is why "yes/no" questions are often closed as too broad.