# Is "is this an example of..." an example of a bad question?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

If a question provides some code and asks "is this an example of *X*" (for some *X*), is such a question off topic? Such questions seem worthless to anyone except the OP, and similar questions could be repeated infinitely. They seem the antithesis of questions useful for building a repository of useful questions and answers. My instinct is that therefore such questions should be off topic. But I struggle to see an applicable close reason, suggesting they are on topic.

The question has a yes/no answer, so clearly not *too broad*. In most cases I'be seen, *X* has a generally accepted precise definition, so not *primarily opinion based*.

Once there was a *too localized* close reason, which would be applicable. But that was removed.

Comment: I close as 'unclear', as in 'unclear why you don't know from your own analysis, what do you expect us to do?', same as 'Explain..', 'Consider..' and all the other do-my-homework tells.

Comment: @Martin James: That comment is worthy of being an answer.

Comment: Besides voting as unclear, I often comment saying something like "If I said the answer is _yes_, does that help you?  I suspect that isn't your actual question."  I've never seen a response, but maybe someday...

Comment: Is ''Is ''Is “is this an example of…” an example of a bad question?'' an example of an example of a good question?'' an example of a ridiculous question? Try saying that out loud

Comment: @cat At least fix the quote marks. "Is 'Is "Is 'is this an example of…' an example of a bad question?" an example of an example of a good question?' an example of a ridiculous question?" Also, why did you add *two* levels on top? lol

Comment: @cat Because that's the standard syntax. If you quote a quote, you alternate the quote marks to make it at least a little simpler to match up the marks. It's like alternating `()` and `[]` in math. (Although, *normally*, if you have three levels, you should be considering the indent options.)

Comment: I hesitate the ask, but... do you have an example of such a question?

Comment: Hm... If it is, then I have to downvote this question

Comment: Would "Is this code (insert code here) an example of a monad?" be an example of what you're talking about"?

Comment: Haskell Alert!  Abandon Question!

Comment: @JeffreyBosboom: I would argue these questions could actually be useful to the OP... for example if you tell them their search algorithm is a special case of A* then maybe they'll know they should spend some time learning about graph search algorithms.

Comment: I disagree with this being a duplicate. It's asking about a *specific class* of yes/no questions that is **not** covered by the answers in that thread. The suggestion to edit is only slightly applicable, since turning it into an acceptable question would require essentially discarding the original question.

Answer (score 9):

You're right. There doesn't appear to be a directly applicable close reason. "Unclear what you're asking," doesn't apply as that reason specifies:

> As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Trying to close it according to that reason is pretty clearly just tying to shoehorn it into *any* existing close reason.

That said, these are not *good* questions in most cases. I could imagine there are some examples and concepts where there is an answer and it's instructive to study, but these would likely be few and far between. I can think of a few options for dealing with the more common low-quality ones.

- **Downvote**. It *clearly* fits that description:

  > This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not useful.

  This isn't especially satisfying since someone could post an answer and gain reputation since it will remain open, which in the long term magnifies the "help vampire" problem.

  Regardless of what else you do, go ahead and do this one anyway for low quality questions.
- **Find a dupe**. In the case you're describing, we could argue that this would be a duplicate of a question that asks for a definition or explanation of X, since the answer would be a fairly simple application of the information there.

  This also has a fairly big problem. Namely, that a question of that kind likely has more business being on Programmers than StackOverflow or may be otherwise off-topic here. We wouldn't want to migrate a low quality question to Programmers just to close it as a dupe, either.

  But if one can be found, this is absolutely a good way of dealing with the question. If you determine that a question about an explanation or the definition of X would be on topic but can't find a question, you could create and self answer one to serve as a canonical question on it. Then you would close as a dupe of the one you create.
- **Post an answer explaining or defining X**. Instead of trying to create another question to close as a dupe, you could answer this one with the full explanation or definition of the concept X. You would have to explain how it is an example, but now you've produced a situation where other questions about the same topic could be closed as a duplicate.

  Consider improving the question as much as possible if you do this. Perhaps even go so far as to rewrite the question to be more general instead of about a specific example. (You would probably want to run that by the OP first.)
- **Close using Other**. We *do* have an "Other" close reason, for exceptional cases. If you feel *very* strongly that a question is so poor it should be closed, you can vote to close using Other and provide an explanation. It will be up to other users whether they agree your course of action is correct or not, but it is a possibility.

  You could cite the Help pages in coming up with your reason. A few general principles came to mind for me:

  [On topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) requires that questions be about:

  > - a specific programming problem, or
  > - a software algorithm, or
  > - software tools commonly used by programmers; and is
  > - a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development

  If it's not about a specific algorithm, then you could argue it doesn't fall into any of these. (The last one wouldn't apply since the question of *categorizing* things is really more of a theoretical aspect that a practical problem.)

  SO prefers questions that

  > - inspire answers that explain “why” and “how”
  > - tend to have long, not short, answers

  From [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

  Technically, these are the subjective guidelines, but you could make a case that good questions that aren't about specific code issues should have these qualities (and that even with code, these are often preferred).

  > Questions asking for *homework help* must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.

  From [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

  I'm generalizing a bit by throwing these questions into "homework help," but this sort of question *would* be typical of homework.

  So in short, while there isn't a specific applicable close reason, there *does* seem to be ample evidence that SO's philosophy is hostile toward the low quality variety of these questions. This could be used to build a case for closing using Other.

Comment: So in short: It's not really a clear case and it has to be decided on a case by case basis and some of this questions can be okay while others may not? Or: All question of this type need to be closed with very high likelihood by some fitting custom close reason?

Comment: @Trilarion Case by case. The real question, imo, is, "Would others be able to learn something useful and not obvious from the example?" If it's trivial, close it or turn it into a canonical resource. If it's not, either answer or migrate to a more appropriate site.

Comment: What I don't like about qestions of type "Is this ...?" is that they are too specific and only require yes/no answers in principle. I guess almost always you can convert them into "What is...?". In this case it would be "What is a good example for X?". I can imagine that these questions are useful in the majority of cases. Actually, they would be the core of the planned documentation/tutorial feature on SO, I guess.

Comment: @Trilarion "What is a good example for X?" would be "Too Broad". "There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format," (from the close reason description) and, "every answer is equally valid" from [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) apply.

Comment: Oh, now it get's interesting. If "What is a good example for X?" is too broad and "Is this a good example for X?" may often be not useful and gets downvoted, then how can anyone ever ask for a good example of X on SO? Seems like a pretty tough challenge.

Comment: @Trilarion That's correct. You shouldn't ask for an example. You should lay out your confusion about the concept and ask for specific clarification about your confusion. (Seriously consider whether it belongs on SO, though. Often, I believe either Programmers or Comp Sci would be more appropriate for conceptual questions like those.) Most likely, an example will be provided in the answer. If not, you could request one in comments on a provided answer.

Comment: Okay. I guess that the planned documentation section of SO kind of closes the gap and questions for examples will have a home there. Making meaningful but generic examples surely is a documentation task.

Answer (score -8):

Yes this is an example of a bad question

Comment: This answer is an example of a bad answer to a question asking if something is an example of X. Sorry.

Comment: @jpmc26 The irony...lol

Comment: @jpmc26 Is "This answer is an example of a bad answer to a question asking if something is an example of X. Sorry." a good example of a comment on an answer about "'Is "Is 'is this an example of…' an example of a bad question?" an example of an example of a good question?' an example of a ridiculous question?" being an example of a bad question?

Comment: It's also a classical example of the kind of answer I find myself writing because SO rejects "Yes" and "No" as too short. I hate software that doesn't let me choose my own words to express myself.

Comment: It's not failing to let you choose your words, it's forcing you to choose your words.

Comment: @MichaelKay, don't write such answers. Answer containing only "yes" or "no" from a stranger (unless you are well known as an expert in X, but those will never answer just "yes" or "no") is really useless. Prove your words with either good example or explanation of why it's "yes" or "no". E.g. "Yes. Such questions are bad because ..."

Comment: @MichaelKay SO has specific goals. It aims to be a repository of useful knowledge, a place you can come to *learn*. Yes/no answers might answer the *immediate* question, but they don't teach you enough to be able to apply the knowledge in a wider variety of situations. You wouldn't expect Wikipedia to be satisfied with a one sentence summary of a topic; they want more in depth information. SO might not be the place to go as in depth as Wikipedia, and it certainly is a place for a different type of information. But that doesn't mean that shallow answers fit with its goals.

Comment: Well, I've been in the position where after saying "Yes" I just didn't know what I could usefully add, because I didn't know why they were asking. If they want to know more, they can always ask a supplementary.

Comment: @MichaelKay The best action to take in that case would to ask in comments why they want to know or what they're confused about. Once they clarify, then you have something to go on for creating a more in depth answer. Or you could just expound on the details with information you think they might find useful.