# Was I wrong to vote to close this question on the basis that it seemed to be asking for recommendations?

Tags: discussion, questions, vote-to-close, closed-questions

I voted to close [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53625230/c-sharp-programmatic-pdf-manipulation-library), where the opening line starts:

> Is there a C# PDF manipulation library that will allow me to reference all annotations and what not, insert text and other components, from/into the PDF, all programmatically?

I interpreted this as asking for library recommendations, and voted to close it as off-topic. Four other users agreed with me, so it got closed.

OP has now countered stating that it wasn't a request for recommendations, but instead a straight-forward yes/no question with any recommendations being a happy accident:

> This is a simple yes or no question. If I get recommendations then that's even better. This is as straight yes or no question. Its fact or not fact if it exists.

I understand that "is there a ...." can be used for a simple yes/no answer in English, but that it's typically used when seeking recommendations (e.g. "is there a supermarket near here?"), so I guess I can see both sides of it.

At the time of writing, there is one re-open vote against the question, which makes me wonder if I did the wrong thing voting to close the question, even though it initially seemed to be seeking recommendations.

Did I do the wrong thing? Should I vote to re-open it?

Comment: You did the right thing. Look at the OP's comments on the answers: they are only going to mark an answer as correct if the suggested library works for them *after testing it*. Something they couldn't do unless the answer contained a recommendation. If they were only looking for a yes/no, not a specific library, then they should have just accepted the first answer that said yes.

Comment: @BSMP I hadn't considered that, but that does make a lot of sense. It's makes it clear what they were asking for, despite what they've said since in the Q's comments.

Comment: The mischievous side of me would like to orchestrate things so the poster gets exactly one answer, "Yes, there is such a library", and no more information than that. Hopefully it would make the point about why that's a pretty lousy question if not taken as a recommendation question.

Comment: *"OP has now countered stating that it wasn't a request for recommendations, but instead a straight-forward yes/no question..."* Classic twittery, VTC and move on... :-)

Comment: see also: [Where is the line for yes/no questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/258636/839601) at MSO and my favorite from MSE: [Question closed because yes/no answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183183/165773)

Comment: What if someone asked a yes or no question about the existence of a library and one person answered "no" and the other answered "yes". Exactly how would that be useful to anybody?

Comment: even better we could migrate it to softwarerecs.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @azerafati I forgot that that even existed :-O

Comment: Whats strange is the votes to un-delete it, this question should stayed dead and buried

Comment: Replying to *'Is it possible to ...'* questions with *'Of course it's possible.'* is considered by diamond mods to be "snarky and condescending". If that's the policy then what does that make the question?

Comment: You did the right thing. *Is there a library?* is absolutely useless, and will be  followed up the vast majority of times by a comment that says *Can you tell me what it is and where to find it?*. It's a useless question that has no future value at best, and at worst it's an intentional effort to circumvent the guidelines by trying to disguise the intent of the post.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You did the right thing. "Is there a library for X" is just a thinly veiled recommendation question.

Or, to answer in C#, which the question was originally phrased in:

> Do any classes implement this abstract class?
>
> ```
> public abstract class BaseLibrary {
>     public abstract String GetRecommendation();
>
>     public bool Exists() {
>         return GetRecommendation() != null;
>     }
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you, especially for the C# example. Between this answer and BSMP's comment about how they handled the answers to their question, it now seems quite clear what they really wanted.

Answer (score 12):

Another thing worth mentioning: Askers purport to only ask if such a library exists, but just taking that at face value, neither, "Yes", nor, "No" fit the minimum character limit for answers.  And, to be honest, both of those are not very good answers.

These types of questions carry the implicit expectation that you're going to back up your answer with proof, which is exactly what the asker wants in the first place.  "Yes, this library here does that" is going to be the only valid answer to those types of questions.

Asking for the existence of a library is still a recommendation.  Especially for our quality standards, where even just answering the question at face value wouldn't actually *be* an answer.

Comment: "Yes, such a library exists. Identifying it is left as an exercise for the reader." ;-)

Comment: I disagree with _"answering the question at face value wouldn't actually be an answer"_. It seems to me that such an answer would in fact _be_ an answer.

Comment: "No, such a library does not exist anywhere in the observable universe. Source: [...]". Joking aside, a definitive "No"-answer would only be possible if the task was somehow proveably impossible. That leaves "Yes" as the only possible answer, which isn't really usefull for anyone.